# detect active <li> for jQuery carousel (pagination)

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

My alteration / attempt to jQuery Carousel script can be found below; However to my dismay, the active class isn't attaching correctly and rather just always shows the first `<li>` as active. I would also like the ability to 'click' each `<li>` representing pagination so it can go to that slide. It's a very small 3-image carousel. Please take a gandar and feast your eyes at my **[jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yam5ma96/5/).** If any suggestions that work, please present thee.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    /**
     * Check if first li element is hidden
     * then show
     */
    if( jQuery('.carouselNav li:first-child').is(':hidden') ) {
        // Toggle visibility
        jQuery('.carouselNav li:first-child').toggle();
         jQuery('.carouselPagination li:first-child').addClass('active');
    }
    // Interval time
    var carouselInterval = 5000;
    // Slider
    function carouselSlide(){
        // Check if last element was reached
        if( jQuery('.carouselNav li:visible').next().length == 0 ) {
            // Hide last li element
            jQuery('.carouselNav li:last-child').slideUp('fast');
            // Show the first one
            jQuery('.carouselNav li:first-child').slideDown('fast');

            jQuery('.carouselPagination li:last-child').removeClass('active');
            jQuery('.carouselPagination li:first-child').addClass('active');
        } else {
            // Rotate elements
            jQuery('.carouselNav li:visible').slideUp('fast').next('li:hidden').slideDown('fast');
            jQuery('.carouselPagination active').removeClass('active').next('li').addClass('active');
        }
    }
    // Set Interval
    var carouselScroll = setInterval(carouselSlide,carouselInterval);
    // Pause on hover
    jQuery('.carousel').hover(function() {
        clearInterval(carouselScroll);
    }, function() {
        carouselScroll = setInterval(carouselSlide,carouselInterval);
        carouselSlide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few minor fixes in your code:

First of all, you are looking for list item with "active" class, so ensure that the first list item has "active" class.

```
<li class="active">
```

Secondly "jQuery('.carouselPagination active')" is missing dot before active to select by class name.

```
jQuery('.carouselPagination li.active').removeClass('active').next('li').addClass('active');
```

Here's the code with the fixes and clicking ability. The code is messy, but it should give you an idea how to start. https://jsfiddle.net/x89wxoqu/